# How to install GD on Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, gd

I am running Laravel 5.3 and trying to do some image manipulation. I get this error: GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.

I've tried putting gd in my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
    "mews/purifier": "~2.0",
    "vinkla/hashids": "^2.4",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.2",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "gd": "*"
},
```

and it didn't work. I also tried:

```
"ext-gd": "*"
```

and that didn't work either. I looked at this page https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support and it says:

The following built-in extensions have been built “shared” and can be enabled through composer.json (internal identifier names given in parentheses)

GD (gd)

Comment: Is your `composer.json` in the root of your repository? Are you tracking `composer.lock`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add `"gd": "*"`  to composer.json and perform `composer update`

If that doesn't work add `"ext-gd":" *"` and do a composer update

Comment: Those sound like instructions for Windows. There is no way to "put a file in the `ext` folder" on Heroku.

Comment: Sorry my bad. However `"ext-gd": "*" ` should've worked

Comment: I know it's a stupid question. You did do a `composer update` right?

Comment: Cheers mate! Glad I could help. PS sorry for not reading the whole thing.

Comment: I am getting typo error when I run composer update. Also, it says the "gd" is deprecated and should use a package name instead. How do I go about this

Comment: @leeCoder did you try `"ext-gd":" *"`

Answer (score 14):

I run **`composer require ext-gd`** and `git push heroku master` it did work.

I tried add `"gd": "*"` to composer.json and perform `composer update` but when push to Heroku meet error with `Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag' not found`. I think it's not only update `ext-gd` with `composer update`

Answer (score 2):

#### In composer.json file

```
"require": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.3.6",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3",
        "ext-gd": "*"

    },
```

#### Update composer and push to origin branch

```
composer update

git add .

git commit -m "message"

git push origin <branch name>
```

#### Rebuild your project at Heroku

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions

Comment: It took 4 years and 2 months but you answered, thank you @user9712543!

Comment: For php 7.2, `sudo apt install php7.2-gd && sudo service apache2 restart` also needed as I  had none

Comment: Thanks. but after doing this i get `419 | page expired error` on heroku

Answer (score 0):

I did the same instructions but I have this problem after i run composer update on heroku.

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-gd * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:

```
 - /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php-cli.ini
 - /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/conf.d/000-heroku.ini
 - /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/conf.d/010-ext-zend_opcache.ini
 - /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/conf.d/100-ext-mbstring.ini
```

You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-gd` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.